# Reading into a string from a file, but any text after space on a line removed?

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, ignore-case

I have a large text file with phrases such as:

```
citybred JJ 
Brestowe NNP 
STARS NNP NNS
negative JJ NN
investors NNS NNPS
mountain NN
```

My objective is to keep the first word of each line, without the spaces, and also make them lowercase.
EX:

```
citybred 
brestowe
stars
negative
investors
mountain
```

Would be returned if the above text was evaluated.

Any help?

Current code:

```
public class FileLinkList
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        String content = new String();
        File file = new File("abc.txt");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                content = sc.nextLine();
                list.add(content);
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
        }

        Collections.reverse(list);
        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("Node " + (count++) + " : ");
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry :) just had to
cut -d' ' -f1 inventory.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your token and its POS tag is separated by space :

```
public class FileLinkList{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
            LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
            String word;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LEXICON.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                            word = sCurrentLine.trim().split(" ")[0];
                            list.add(word.toLowerCase());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of all comments, I believe yours works best for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
content = sc.nextLine();
string[] tokens = content.split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemovEemptyEntries);
// You can add some validations here...
string word = tokens[0].ToLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class FileLinkList {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        String content = new String();
        int count=1;
        File file = new File("abc.txt");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                content = sc.nextLine();
                if (content != null && content.length() > 0)) {
                    list.add(content.trim().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
        }

        for (String listItem : list) {
            System.out.println(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) it is much simpler to read a file into a list of Strings.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("abc.txt"));
List<String firstWords = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
  String firstWord = line.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
  firstWords.add(firstWord);
}
```